# A RESTful query from Angular to Sails.js with dates

Tags: angularjs, sails.js, waterline

I'm using sails-mysql adapter for Waterline to connect Sails,js with my Mysql database that stores dates in this format: "YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS".
With default Sails.js blueprints untouched I'm doing the following query from an Angular.js service:

```
CheckAvailability: function(arrival,departure,room){

                departure = moment(departure).endOf('day').format();

                arrival = moment(arrival).startOf('day').format();

                var bookingList = $resource(IP_ADDRESSES.dbserver+'bookings');

                return bookingList.query({

                    or:[{                            
                                departure: {'>=': arrival},
                                departure: {'<=': departure}                                                     

                        },{
                                arrival:{'>=':arrival},
                                arrival:{'<=':departure}

                        },{
                                arrival: {'<=': arrival},
                                departure: {'>=': departure}
                        }

                    ],

                    where:{room:room}}).$promise;
}
```

The returned result is not correct, I get all the reservation from the selected room, instead of receiving only overbooked rooms.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This

```
or:[{                            
  departure: {'>=': arrival},
  departure: {'<=': departure}
},{
  arrival:{'>=':arrival},
  arrival:{'<=':departure}
},{
  arrival: {'<=': arrival},
  departure: {'>=': departure}
}]
```

is not a valid waterline condition.

The `AND` operator is done by adding multiple operators to the same key:

```
or:[{                            
  departure: {'>=': arrival, '<=': departure},
},{
  arrival:{'>=':arrival, '<=':departure},
},{
  arrival: {'<=': arrival},
  departure: {'>=': departure}
}]
```

---

As an aside, be aware that `var b = {a:1, a:2}` is a Javascript nonsense. You'd get a unique `b.a` property with a value of... well... I guess it totally depends on the implementation (Node.js, browser) and is unpredictable ?

Answer (score 1):

I usually use *ISO 8601* strings in conjonction with `where`.

Moment has `endOf()` and `startOf()` function that you can use to get the "last/fisrt instant of a day", and unparametrized `format()` will convert to an ISO 8601 string:

```
CheckAvailability: function(arrival,departure,room){
  arrival = moment(arrival);
  departure = moment(departure);

  var bookingList = $resource(IP_ADDRESSES.dbserver+'bookings');

  return bookingList.query({
    or:[{                            
      departure: {'>=': arrival.startOf('day').format()},
      departure: {'<=': departure.endOf('day').format()}                                                     
    },{
      arrival:{'>=':arrival.startOf('day').format()},
      arrival:{'<=':departure.endOf('day').format()}
    },{
      arrival: {'<=': arrival.endOf('day').format()},
      departure: {'>=': departure.startOf('day').format()}
    }],
    where:{room:room}})
  .$promise;
```

Comment: In addition, note that *ISO 8601* format is localized, whereas *YYYY-MM-DD* is not. With iso 8601, you compare real dates whereas your solution compare a non localized string projection that is dangerous.

Comment: thank you for your correct suggestion, I've edited the question accordingly, unfortunately I get the same wrong result.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure mixing `query` and `where` along in the same request does work ? I think it *should* work, thanks to implicit `actionUtil.parseCriteria(req)` call on blueprints routes; but it'd be worth giving a try embedding your date query **inside** `where`. Sounds like `where` is the only handled condition, isnt't it ?

---

NB: will grab the link for `parseCriteria` later, I'm on iPad right now.

Comment: I'm using this code just for test and narrowing down the issue : `return bookingList.query({where:{arrival:{'>=': arrival},arrival:{'<':departure},booking_n:{'!':booking_n}},limit:10}).$promise;`  the first arrival condition get ignored, in fact inverting the position of the two arrivals I get different results.

Comment: I think `arrival:{'>=': arrival},arrival:{'<':departure}` is invalid in waterline conditions. Go for `arrival:{'>=': arrival, '<':departure}` if you need an `AND` operator

Comment: I formulate a complete answer below